# The relation is not parented to the table to which this DataView points

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, user-controls, repeater

```
<BusinessList>
  <Company>
    <CompanyName>StackOverflow</CompanyName>
    <Desc>FAQ Q & A Site</Desc>
    <Email>dummy@dummy.com</Email>
    <Mobile>123456</Mobile>
    <Phone>123456</Phone>
    <City>florida</City>
    <ZipCode>620020</ZipCode>
    <Country>USA</Country>
    <State>FL</State>
    <Image>a.png</Image>
  </Company>
  <Staff>
    <FirstName>A</FirstName>
    <Qualification>Bachelor in Engineering</Qualification>
    <Stories>Highly enthusiastic and energetic programmer will surely work with him again - Jane</Stories>
    <Designation>Chief Engineer</Designation>
    <Email>dummy@dummy.com</Email>
    <ContactNo>123456</ContactNo>
    <Fax>56565656</Fax>
    <Image>1.png</Image>
  </Staff>
  <Staff>
    <FirstName>B</FirstName>
    <Qualification>Bachelor in Engineering</Qualification>
    <Stories>Highly enthusiastic and energetic programmer will surely work with him again - Jane</Stories>
    <Designation>Team Leader</Designation>
    <Email>dummy@dummy.com</Email>
    <ContactNo>123456</ContactNo>
    <Fax>5757575</Fax>
    <Image>2.png</Image>
  </Staff>
  <Staff>
    <FirstName>C</FirstName>
    <Qualification>Bachelor in Engineering</Qualification>
    <Stories>Highly enthusiastic and energetic programmer will surely work with him again - Jane</Stories>
    <Designation>Programmer</Designation>
    <Email>dummy@dummy.com</Email>
    <ContactNo>123456</ContactNo>
    <Fax>565656</Fax>
    <Image>3.png</Image>
  </Staff>
  <Staff>
    <FirstName>D</FirstName>
    <Qualification>Bachelor in Engineering</Qualification>
    <Stories>Highly enthusiastic and energetic programmer will surely work with him again - Jane</Stories>
    <Designation>Developer</Designation>
    <Email>dummy@dummy.com</Email>
    <ContactNo>123456</ContactNo>
    <Fax>1231231234</Fax>
    <Image>4.png</Image>
  </Staff>
</BusinessList>
```

Above is my xml inout file for the Dataset, which i read with `DataSet.ReadXml()` method.However i get a error when i databind with nested repeater like below.

```
                        <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rptrCompany">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                Staff in company
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                Company Details:
                                <%# Eval("CompanyName") %>
                                .. blahblahblah Staff Details
                                <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rptrStaff" datasource='<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem).CreateChildView("BusinessList_Staff") %>'>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        Staff List
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# Eval("FirstName") %>
                                        ..blah blah blah
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
```

blah blah blah part denoted extra fields that i databound. In the child repeater i get the error/exception `The relation is not parented to the table to which this DataView points.`
What am i doing wrong, the relation name "BusinessList_Staff" exists when i checked the dataset[ relation is automatically created by framework for me]. Also `Container.Dataitem` is a `datarowview` which also has 'CreateChildView' method used in markup. All i do is DataBind the parent repeater in backend pageLoad like below
`rptrCompany.DataSource = dtTemp.Tables["Company"].DefaultView;
 rptrCompany.DataBind();`

Please let me know what am i doing wrong

Comment: I can not see any relation in your exported xml.

Comment: @Farzin you mean `BusinessList_Staff` relation i meantioned in markup? try the dataset read cml method and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because the staff are not part of the Company? The only relation that could exist in your XML is an implicit relation to the Company by being after the company.

If you have control over the XML generation you should change the `<Staff>` elements to be contained within the `<Company>`.

Haven't databinding in this fashion in a long time, so sorry if this is not a complete solution.

Comment: does the relation need to exist in this situation? i mean businesslist , Company & Staff are related right. That's why i tried `BusinessList_Staff` as relation name

Comment: you sure are a genius. i did as you suggested and solved the problem. Staff elements are nested inside the Company Now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because your dataset structure is flat. this structure of repeater needs to have a list of staffs in company entity. xml should look like :

```
<BusinessList>
  <Company>
    <!--Other Properties-->
    <Staffs>
      <!--Staff List-->
      <Staff>
      </Staff>
      <Staff>
      </Staff>
    </Staffs>
  </Company>
</BusinessList>
```

Comment: as guvante suggested i did make the Staff elements child of Company and it solved my problem. thanks for the details though voted up.